# Are questions about interacting with users on-topic

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, scope, users

I was going to ask a question about how to get user buy-in to some security changes I'm making at work. I know what changes I want to make, how, and why, but I am looking for advice on how to show these to the user and get them to buy-in that this is a good thing. Is this a question for the InfoSec StackExchange?

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it can be on-topic but the concern will be if it is too opinion-based. Post it and let's see.

Comment: My guess is you may be correct - thanks!